Is this proof of $L^q(\Omega) \subset L^p(\Omega)$ correct?
I am trying to prove the following result :
Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ such that $\lambda(\Omega) < +\infty$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Then, for $1\leq p\leq q \leq +\infty$, we have
$$L^q(\Omega) \subset L^p(\Omega).$$
In the book I am studying, the authors apply Hölder's inequality with exponent $\alpha = \frac{q}{p}$, which is I think the most common way to do it.
Trying to solve the problem, I came up with a different proof and I am not confident that It is correct. Here it is :

First we prove, by applying Hölder inequality for a function $g = 1$ that
$$ ||f||_{L^1({\Omega})} \leq \lambda(\Omega)||f||_{L^q(\Omega)},\quad\forall q\in[1,+\infty] $$
Second, let $1 \leq p \leq q < +\infty$. We have,
$$||f||_{L^p(\Omega)}^p = \int_\Omega |f|^p \leq \int_\Omega \max(|f|, |f|^q)$$
This is because for any real nubmer $\alpha \geq 0$, if $\alpha > 1$, $\alpha^p < \alpha^q$ and if $\alpha \leq 1$, $\alpha^p \leq \alpha$.
Then we obtain,
\begin{align}
||f||_{L^p(\Omega)}^p &\leq \int_\Omega \max(|f|, |f|^q)\\
&\leq \int_\Omega |f| + \int_\Omega |f|^q\\
&\leq \lambda(\Omega)||f||_{L^q(\Omega)} + ||f||_{L^q(\Omega)}^q
\end{align}

Thus, if $||f||_{L^q(\Omega)} < +\infty$ then $||f||_{L^p(\Omega)} < +\infty$, which gives the result.
Is this proof correct for $1 \leq p \leq q < +\infty$?
Thanks a lot !

Yes, that seems correct.

It is correct, up to the exponent on $\lambda(\Omega)$ in the first step (it should be $\lambda(\Omega)^{1-1/q}$).

The first step has a problem. Let $q\in (1, \infty ]$ and let $q'$ be the Hölder conjugate exponent corresponding to $q$. Then $q' \in [1, \infty )$ and by Hölder's inequality you obtain
\begin{equation}
\|f\|_{L^{1}(\Omega )} = \|f \, \mathbb{1}_{\Omega} \|_{L^{1}(\Omega )} \leq \|\mathbb{1}_{\Omega} \|_{L^{q'}(\Omega )} \|f\|_{L^{q}(\Omega )} = \lambda (\Omega )^{1/q'} \|f\|_{L^{q}(\Omega )}
\end{equation}
since a direct calculation shows that $\|\mathbb{1}_{\Omega} \|_{L^{q'}(\Omega )} = \lambda (\Omega )^{1/q'}$.
The current inequality you have stated is false when $\lambda (\Omega ) < 1$. To see why, note that if $\lambda (\Omega ) > 0$, $q\in [1, \infty )$ and assuming your inequality was true, you would have
\begin{equation}
\|\mathbb{1}_{\Omega} \|_{L^{1}(\Omega )} \leq \lambda (\Omega ) \|\mathbb{1}_{\Omega} \|_{L^{q}(\Omega )} = \lambda (\Omega )^{1 + 1/q} < \lambda (\Omega ) = \|\mathbb{1}_{\Omega} \|_{L^{1}(\Omega )}
\end{equation}
which is impossible.
However, with this minor change the proof is still valid. For $1\leq p \leq q < \infty$ and $f\in L^{q}(\Omega )$, you have correctly argued that
\begin{equation}
\int_{\Omega} |f|^{p} \leq \int_{\Omega} \max (|f|, |f|^{q})
\end{equation}
and consequently have
\begin{align*}
\int_{\Omega} |f|^{p} &\leq \int_{\Omega} \max (|f|, |f|^{q}) \\
&\leq \int_{\Omega} |f| + \int_{\Omega} |f|^{q} \\
&\leq \lambda (\Omega )^{1/q} \|f\|_{L^{q}(\Omega )} + \|f\|_{L^{q}(\Omega )}^{q} < \infty ,
\end{align*}
which shows that $f\in L^{p}(\Omega )$ and obtains the desired result.

One can also note that
$$
|f|^p\le 1_{\{|f|\le 1\}}+1_{\{|f|>1\}}|f|^q\le 1+|f|^q.
$$
